# How to truncate by word instead of letter count

Tags: php, truncate

I am printing a title into `<title>$title</title>`. But i am trying to print the title with less characters. The problem is i have a php code that prints it with a limit of characters that i choose. But it doesnt solve for finishing the entire word. Is there a function or a way i can make it so that the rest of the word which is cut off by the character is printed?

Right now this is the code im using.

```
$title="Website.com | ". stripslashes($content['text']);
if ($title{70}) {
  $title = substr($title, 0, 69) . '...';
}else{
  $title = $title;
}
```

So it will print something like `Website.com | Here is your sent...`

But i want it to print the rest of the entire word for example `Website.com | Here is your sentence...`

How can i edit my code or is there a function that allows to call the rest of the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trim back to the last space

```
 $title = substr($title, 0, 69) ;
 $title = substr($title, 0, strrpos($title," ")) . '...';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: Wow this seems so much more simple and it works just like the original? I didnt know this function existed.

Comment: the function `strrpos` does have a third argument, which you can use to even shorten this into a one liner... just a thought :) But then you'd have to use `strpos` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
* trims text to a space then adds ellipses if desired
* @param string $input text to trim
* @param int $length in characters to trim to
* @param bool $ellipses if ellipses (...) are to be added
* @param bool $strip_html if html tags are to be stripped
* @return string 
*/
function trim_text($input, $length, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true) {
//strip tags, if desired
if ($strip_html) {
    $input = strip_tags($input);
}

//no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
    return $input;
}

//find last space within length
$last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
$trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);

//add ellipses (...)
if ($ellipses) {
    $trimmed_text .= '...';
}

return $trimmed_text;
}
?>
```